# String variable from External scripts reads null when it shouldn't?

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, null

I'm making a BreakOut clone in Unity3D. I'm working on the collision between a powerup and the paddle. The powerup has a global string 'type', which decides the type of powerup. It gets assigned after instantiating the powerup.

Thing is, when I access this variable through the OnCollisionEnter in the paddle script, it becomes null, tested with a print. However, if I print the variable after instantiating the powerup, it isn't set to null.

Can anyone clear this up for me? This is my code for the script on the paddle object:

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "powerup")
         {
             if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<PowerUp>().type == "Wide")
             {
                 print ("Wide PU!");
             }
             else if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<PowerUp>().type == "Split")
             {
                 print ("Split PU!");
             } 
             //Only the Else gets executed: the print() only displays 'Type: ', indicating the 'type' variable is null?
             else print("Type: " + other.gameObject.GetComponent<PowerUp>().type);

             Destroy(other.gameObject);
         }
     }
```

This is my code for the script on the PowerUp object:

```
 public string type;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

     }

     //This function acts as a class constructor.
     //It may be called after Initializing this GameObject to set proper Power Up behavior.
     public void Initialize(string type)
     {
         //Test the type string given when a brick breaks in BrickBreak script
         switch (type)
         {
         case "Wide":
             //If the type is 'wide', set proper graphical and logical settings
             renderer.material.color = Color.red;
             type = "Wide";
             print ("Spawn Type: " + type); //This displays the type variable just fine!
             break;
         case "Split":
             renderer.material.color = Color.green;
             type = "Split";
             print ("Spawn Type: " + type); //This displays the type variable just fine!
             break;
         default:
             print ("No proper Power Up constructor string input!");
             break;
         }
     }
```

Comment: do you call Initialize yourself? Sounds like type should rather be assigned in Awake or Start

Comment: Thing is, when you instantiate a GameObject in Unity you can't pass any parameter... like a constructor in standard C#. So instead I made a custom Initialize function and I call that right after the Instantiate() function. Even though it's not in Start() or Awake(), I call that function before any collision with the paddle so it should be fine, right?

Comment: yup that should work fine. Although you should consider using an enum here rather than string comparison.

Comment: Never did that before, I'm still a beginner. Still curious what's going on though.

Comment: oh wait .. x == "string" does not work in all languages, not sure about c#. it's quite possible you have to to something like x.isEqual("string") because the equality test may simply test whether x and "string" are identical pointers, which they can only be if they were the same objects

Comment: Thank you :) That was not the issue though, put most of the logic into the PowerUp script's Awake() and then the variable is set properly for other objects to read. No idea why the other method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I moved most of the logic from the Break script to the PowerUp script's Awake() function... Still don't get why the variable gets set to null but at least this fixes it.